# What is an alternative way to coordinate parallel tasks in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have recently started working with apache airflow and my dags and workflow run perfectly, however, I am looking for another way to coordinate the dependencies by excluding a task within the workflow.

The below code produces the following

```
start >> spark_job >> sql_job>> [getfile,getfile2] >> t2>> [renamefile,renamefile2] >> t8>> t9 
>> t10>> end
```

[image]

I am looking for a way to exclude the *sleep* task where *get_file* connects directly to *Renam_file2* and *get_file2* connects to *Renam_file*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have dependencies between arrays but you can break down the dependencies to achieve direct connection between get_file to Rename_file.

I literally took what you mentioned in description, but are you sure you want to connect get_file to Renam_file2?

```
start >> spark_job >> sql_job >> [getfile, getfile2] 
getfile >> renamefile2  # opposite??
getfile2 >> renamefile  # opposite??
[renamefile, renamefile2] >> t8 >> t9 >> t10 >> end
```